# Chartkick group and order by at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, chartkick

**I have a working chart in chartkick but months are not showing in order**

(October -> March -> February)

**I need them in a correct order**

(February -> March -> October )

**My schema**

```
  create_table "business_data", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "net_sales"
    t.text "next_steps"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "month_name"
    t.date "start_date"
    t.date "end_date"
  end
```

**Controller**

```
@business_data = BusinessDatum.all.order(start_date: :asc)
```

**View**

```
<%= line_chart @business_data.group(:month_name).sum(:net_sales) %>
```

**By adding the `.order` I get the following error:**

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "business_data.start_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...a" GROUP BY "business_data"."month_name" ORDER BY "business_...
```

¿How can I order the months in the correct order?

Comment: Does it not work if you add the `start_date` to the group by? `group(:month_name, :start_date).order(:month_name, :start_date)`

Comment: I think main problem comes from the column `month_name` itself. I would have stored the number of the month and let `i18n` handle the translation. That way, it's pretty easy to sort by month and your app is ready for other countries. 

Answer (score 2):

Like the error msg points out, in a `SELECT` query with aggregate functions, `ORDER BY` only allows references to grouped or aggregated columns. Other references would be ambiguous. **But** - as a quick fix - you can work with an *expression* based on the grouped column `month_name`:

```sql
SELECT month_name, sum(net_sales)
FROM   business_data
GROUP  BY month_name
ORDER  BY to_date(month_name, 'Month');  -- date derived from month name
```

If `start_date` is guaranteed to lie within `month_name`, you can also:

```sql
SELECT month_name, sum(net_sales)
FROM   business_data
GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', start_date), month_name
ORDER  BY date_trunc('month', start_date);
```

This also enforces the same year (like you probably want).

Storing the name of the month is not very useful to begin with. (What about the year anyway?)

If possible, fix your relational design to store a `date` instead.
Or, if `start_date` always lies within `month_name`, simply drop the column `month_name`. It's just redundant ballast. Don't store redundant data. You can derive the name of the month from `start_date` cheaply with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(start_date, 'Month') AS month_name
```

However, to group and order by month, throw in `date_trunc()` like above:

```sql
SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', start_date), 'Month') AS month_name, sum(net_sales)
FROM   business_data
GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', start_date)
ORDER  BY date_trunc('month', start_date);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=db32241b8cd09e4124a3c0b6abd5aa84)*

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

You can try finding the aggregates sales per `month_name`, and then sort them

Here is what that looks like

```
<%= line_chart BusinessDatum.all.group(:month_name).sum(:net_sales).sort_by {|s| Date::MONTHNAMES.index(s[0])} %>
```

Note: I put the whole query on a single line, but that should work even if you break it between controller and action (or preferably move completely into the controller action)

**Longer Discussion:**

Based on the question, I am going to guess that there is a conceptual misunderstanding about how ActiveRecord/Postgres is executing your query. If you look at the original query

```
BusinessDatum.all.order(start_date: :asc).group(:month_name).sum(:net_sales)
```

the SQL that this expression would generate is

```
; SQL generated by AR
SELECT 
  SUM("net_sales"), "month_name"
FROM 
  "business_data" 
GROUP BY 
  "month_name" 
ORDER BY 
  "start_date" ASC
```

I am gonna guess that you were expecting Postgres to first order the data by `start_date` and then do a `group_by` (assuming that if grouping is applied to the ordered data, the aggregations will be ordered as well). However, that is not how Postgres works.

In fact, if we change the query to have `order by` before `group by`, it would be an invalid query. The following is an invalid query

```
; this query is invalid because the order of order by and group by is not correct
SELECT 
  SUM("net_sales"), "month_name"
FROM 
  "business_data" 
ORDER BY 
  "start_date" ASC
GROUP BY 
  "month_name"
```

Let's dig a little more. If you look at the SQL generated by AR, the error that you are seeing gets clear. Postgres is going to take the data in the table, group the data by month, and then sum the `net_sales`. When it does that the outcome will contain only the `sum(net_sales)` and `month_name`. The data will look something like this

| sum(net_sales) | month_name |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | October |
| 200 | February |
| 300 | March |

As you can see, the grouped data does not contain the `start_date`. In fact, it probably would not make sense to have a single `start_date` here as the `start_date` column can contain lots of values. This is why the error you saw gave you two options to fix:

1. Either use `start_date` in the `group by` clause (so that the `start_date` is part of the grouped data (which will then allow you to order by `start_date`. If you add `start_date` in the group clause though, the data will look something like this (the `month_name` and `start_date` are no longer unique in the grouped data

| sum(net_sales) | month_name | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | October | Oct 1, 2022 |
| 50 | October | Oct 2, 2022 |
| 200 | February | Feb 1, 2022 |
| 300 | March | March 5, 2022 |

2. use the start_date in the aggregate function (such as `max(start_date)` )

I don't think either of the two suggestions makes sense in this case.

Note, that the aggregated data does not guarantee that the data is ordered by `month_name` by default. You can try `order by month_name`. However, I do not think that will give you data in the order you want because `order by month_name` will use the alphabetic ordering of months.

So, one solution would be to generate the aggregate on the database as follows:

```
# you do not need the "all" here; it should work without it
@business_data = BusinessDatum.all.group(:month_name).sum(:net_sales)`
```

The generated data will contain the `month_name` (as strings). The output of the above expression will be a hash

```
{"March" => 300, "February" => 200, "October" => 300}
```

You can then sort this data on the application server (i.e. within rails)

```
@business_data.sort_by {|s| Date::MONTHNAMES.index(s[0])}
```

This will generate the data in the calendar month order

```
[ ["February", 200], ["March", 300], ["October", 100] ]
```

Here the `sort` method converted the hash to an array while sorting, but that is okay (probably preferable over hash as arrays communicate ordering) since chartkick can take array or hash as arguments for line chart. If, for some reason, you do want a hash, you can convert it to hash by using the `to_h` function on the array.

Caveat: One assumption that I made here is that Business Data can have multiple entries for a given month, where the `start_date` for entries in a given month, may or may not be unique.